# Base Controller in Habitat

Tags: habitat, controller

We are using habitat in our project. In most of our controller class of each feature, we are doing a same service call.

So we are planning to have a Base Controller to avoid duplicates.

Since we have different project for each feature in Habitat, how can we implement this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right place from my point of view  to implement BaseController is in Foundation Layer.

In this way all features project can inherit from it.

In our solution we have a project  "*.Foundation.Kernel" where we have a BaseControler class.

```
namespace YourSolutionName.Foundation.Kernel.Controllers
{
    public class ControllerBase : SitecoreController
    {
       //yoour code 
    }
}
```